# mobileinit event documentation for JQuery Mobile 1.3.x

Tags: jquery-mobile

Where is the documentation of the `mobileinit` event for JQuery Mobile 1.3.x?

It isn't in the [Events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) API documentation page.

Comment: Not all of them are mentioned in docs. Are you looking for a specific event? http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the `mobileinit` event documentation. It seems to be the page you mentioned. Please add it as the answer.

Comment: If you want a specific widget or settings to override, please let me know, otherwise I'll write a comprehensive answer on all widgets.

Comment: @Omar, this isn't about widgets, it's about events, specifically, where is the documentation for the mobileinit event. For instance, the pageinit event is documented [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/). Since the mobileinit event is not listed on the [Events documentation page](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) I was having trouble finding its documentation. The [page you mentioned](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/) is the answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were looking for a specific widget. I'm glad I've been of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the `mobileinit` event is in this page:

[Configuring Defaults](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/)